# How would I make it it so text dosent go off the screen in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

So I'm using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -loop 1 -framerate 10 -i background.jpg -filter_complex "[1:v]drawtext=text='Hello World':fontfile=payback.ttf:fontsize=200:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy -movflags +faststart -shortest output.mp4
```

The issue is that it goes off the screen, how would I make it go down to the line under it instead of going off the screen.

Comment: There's no line wrap implemented - has to be done using multiple filters or via textfile.

Comment: How would I do with text file?

Comment: You put the text in a file on multiple lines and use textfile option in filter.

Comment: @MrPigbot See examples in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22719247/1109017). Or use subtitles filter instead for auto-wrapping (also shown in same answer).